# How to work with rails form and jsonb postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, jsonb

I'm looking at using the new jsonb capability in Rails4.2 and Postgres4.1.

I was looking at creating a model which represents a user profile (i.e. skill sets, etc) and storing the whole thing in a single jsonb dataset.

So the table would have:

```
id int
profile jsonb
timestamps
```

I was thinking I could basically store all the profile data in the jsonb structure as follows (this is just an example/concept):

```
{
  "basics": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "label": "Programmer",
    "picture": "",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(912) 555-4321",
    "website": "http://johndoe.com",
    "summary": "A summary of John Doe...",
    "location": {
      "address": "2712 Broadway St",
      "postalCode": "CA 94115",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "region": "California"
    },
    "profiles": [{
      "network": "Twitter",
      "username": "john",
      "url": "http://twitter.com/john"
    }]
  },
"skills": [{
    "name": "Web Development",
    "level": "Master",
    "keywords": [
      "HTML",
      "CSS",
      "Javascript"
    ]
  }],
  "languages": [{
    "language": "English",
    "fluency": "Native speaker"
  }],
}
```

My question is how would I create a basic rails form that would write/read to this structure?  I understand how to do it to a traditional relational set of tables, but not sure how to approach when it could all go into a flexible structure like the below?

What would happen at the _form.html.erb and in the controller new/create/edit actions?

Comment: I am in the same situation. Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`store_accessors`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html). Form data is just a `Hash`, that could be easily converted to a `JSON` object and persisted in postgresql without major problems.

Assuming your form submits all profile data in a `profile[]` hash and your models look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  store_accessor :profile
end
```

You could simply do something like:

```
user.profile = params[:profile]
user.profile.save
```

In your controller (or anywhere else) and it should work.

Comment: awesome!  any downsides or gotchas to watch out for?

Comment: @cman77 Rails is doing a lot of serializing/deserializing for you without you knowing. As usual with Rails, when it works it looks like magic, but might cause some trouble. Watch out for non-conventional data structures. Everything that can be safely serialized into JSON should work fine, though.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know about the previous versions but **in Rails 6** from the doc: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

you can use store like this:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
    store :my_jsonb_field_name, accessors: [:property1, :property2]
end
```

Now if you have a form with `<%= form.text_field :property1 %>` and `<%= form.text_field :property2 %>` they will be automatically mapped to your json/jsonb field and you will be able to treat them like if they were a regular (varchar/string) fields.

Do Not forget to permit :property1 and property2 etc in your strong parameters, i.e:

```
params.require(:my_model).permit(:title, [...], :property1, :property2)
```